# CakePHP empty passedArgs

Tags: cakephp, formhelper

I have a form in the View:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Customers', array('action' => 'index'));
echo $this->Form->input('category_id');
echo $this->Form->end('Search');
```

And a method in the Controller:

```
function index() {
    debug($this->passedArgs);
}
```

But the debug message prints out an empty array.

When I type out the url by hand:

```
http://domainna.me/admin/customers/index/category_id:4
```

the debug message prints out:
    Array
    (
        [season_id] => 16
    )

and everything behaves how I want it to. What am I missing?

-----Edit------

debug($this->request->params) prints:

```
Array
(
    [plugin] => 
    [controller] => customers
    [action] => index
    [named] => Array
        (
        )

    [pass] => Array
        (
        )

    [isAjax] => 
)
```

Comment: I think you're missing a question. :)  (ie what are you trying to do / hoping to achieve / expecting)

Comment: Try with `debug($this->request->params)` and check, what it prints?

Comment: @Dave: When the form is submitted, I want the url to look like in the example above.

Comment: @ArunJain I've put the output of debug($this->request->params) in the main post--it is similarly empty of useful information.

Comment: I would really try to reword the entire question.  I've read it 3 times and still don't know what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the GET part:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create

then it will use the get-urls instead of a post.

but i would still advice you to use a sophisticated search plugin like cake dcs:
https://github.com/CakeDC/search

there you will have your desired outcome the right way (using a PRG redirect). with all the powerful features included.

Comment: I would prefer not to use GET because that makes the URLS look different, e.g. index?category_id=4, and I'd like to do this in a more CakePHP-ish way.

Comment: nono, `?cat=4` has nothing to do with cake or its get/post (its the non-rewrite-url way). for cake "/foo:bar/second:one/..." is GET and form post on an /controller/action is POST.